Mariadb query gives variable performance - why and how to diagnose
I have a simple table
desc house.solar;




Field
Type
Null
Key
Default
Extra




ts
datetime
YES

NULL



measurement
varchar(15)
YES

NULL



unit
varchar(10)
YES

NULL



value
float
YES

NULL




against which I execute the following query
select  hour(ts),avg(value)
    from  solar
    where  month(ts)=4
      and  measurement = 'DP1'
      and  year(ts)=2023
    group by  hour(ts);

Sometimes the query takes a long time to execute.
I do this both from a C++/Qt 6.6.2 app and via the linux mysql command.  Sometimes the query runs in "zero" time and then after a few repetitions (with different years, etc) it takes a couple of seconds. A a result the app sometimes is OK then change a parameter and it times out.  I don't think I am asking a lot of the database  but... any pointers as to performance issues with the query?  Next any pointers as to how to diagnose the database performance?
TIA
Update
explain select hour(ts),avg(value) from house.solar where month(ts)=5 and  measurement = 'DP1' and year(ts)=2023 group by hour(ts);




id
select_type
table
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
Extra




1
SIMPLE
solar
ALL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
2959613
Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort



CREATE TABLE `solar` (
  `ts` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `measurement` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unit` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` float DEFAULT NULL
)


when asking performance questions, please always include output of explain select ...rest of your query and show create table yourtablename (for every table used in the query)

short answer is this would benefit from having a (measurement,ts) index and rewriting the where to ts >= '2023-04-01' and ts < '2023-05-01' and measurement='DP1'

Added as reqested to the question

Thanks I will try that and see if it makes any difference, though I dont think it explains why the performance varies from run to run but I am guessing it is to do with the overuse of hour and year functions somehow.  I will comment when I have done it but it will be a day or so due to other commitments.

Use ANALYZE FORMAT=JSON, or if true stuck on how it make the decision look at optimzer trace.

Fantastic @ysth The change in the where clause didn't impact it but adding the index was a great improvement.

without the change to the where, it will just be using the measurement part of the index, so will have to read through all the index records for the measurement instead of jumping straight to the correct date range.  if that is good enough, then the index can just be on (measurement).


Since unit is always the same for a given measurement, get rod of that column.  (Shrinking the table helps some with speed.)

Every table should have a PRIMARY KEY; I recommend this
PRIMARY KEY(measurement, ts)


That PK, plus the following change to the WHERE should run faster:
WHERE measurement = 'DP1'
  AND ts >= '2023-04-01'
  AND ts  < '2023-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH


For further performance improvements, build and maintain a Summary Table

See also Implementation of sensor database in MySQL

MONTH() and YEAR() are not sargable .


